# How to determine if 3d point lie in a certain volume or not?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a set of 3d points in a txt file in the form of (x,y,z) as shown in figure 1. I want to specify the boundaries of these points as in figure 2 such that if any new points were added outside the boundaries they are deleted as the blue points, and if they are inside the boundaries as the green ones they are kept. How can I achieve that in python? I tried convex hull but it only gets the boundary points !

The real data can be found here, I used figures for simplification. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ei9NaJHN922pYItK2CRIXyLfwqm_xgrt/view?usp=sharing

```
Figure 1
```

[image]

```
Figure 2
```

[image]

Comment: Once you know the boundary points for figure 1, using convex hull, test each new point to determine if it is inside or outside the boundary.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking, how to determine the region defined by the boundary points. In other words I have the outside (points) representing boundaries, what's next? what's the condition of the if condition?

Comment: I suggest you think about how you would do it using pencil and paper.  Then convert that approach to code.  If you are still having problems, ask a specific question related to your issue.  StackOverflow is not here to provide a coding service or tutoring service.

Answer (score 1):

For 2D points, you can apply the test as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon):

*One simple way of finding whether the point is inside or outside a simple polygon is to test how many times a ray, starting from the point and going in any fixed direction, intersects the edges of the polygon. If the point is on the outside of the polygon the ray will intersect its edge an even number of times. If the point is on the inside of the polygon then it will intersect the edge an odd number of times. The status of a point on the edge of the polygon depends on the details of the ray intersection algorithm.*

The n-dimensional case involves a convex hull test and requires linear programming techniques as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4442002/58610).